# How to display data depending on FieldName - Access

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, data-binding

I have it so there is a combobox with its selections called the fieldnames of my database. I want it so when you select "SalesCustomers" and press the search button it will display all the customers that has the "Salescustomer" Field names ticked (AKA in true state) otherwise throw an error saying no members of the salescustomer. I have it so it displays all clients depending on the id but i now want it like this. Below is a screenshot of my database and my code.

Code:

```
Private Sub Interest(ByVal ans As String)
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM tbl WHERE ID = ?"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ans
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If reader.Read() Then
        TxtCI.Text = reader(0).ToString()
    Else
        MsgBox("No interest", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Please reselect")
    End If
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: What you describe is a filter, but the method shown indicates a search?

Comment: So i need a filter to use this? The code i was hoping to use is the one above as i use the above code to search for a client using CustomerID. What would the code be for a filter? Never did anything with filters before D:

Comment: Well, I dont know that is why I asked.  Are you trying to find a specific customer of a certain type or are you trying to modify the view to show ALL customer of that type?

Comment: I need to display all customers who has lets say "SalesCustomer" ticked. So when im adding a customer and i tick salescustomer and i make 5 of them and 5 of businesscustomer and i select salescustomer from my combobox i want it to show only the salescustomers.

Comment: `bsCust.Fitler = "SalesCustomer = True"`

Comment: So with the following above i wont need the whole: Select * from etc etc? :o

Comment: Nope, that is what Steve, jmcilhinney and I have been trying to tell you for days: if you take the time to setup the DataAdapter and related objects, most of the code you have goes away.  Even those little Move.. buttons if you add a BindingNavigator

Comment: haha true there! How do i go about setting up this bscust? O_o will i use: bssample.filter or?

Comment: I dont recall what it is named, but it is the BindingSource you are using.  Be sure to have a way to remove the filter...such as a "(None)" in the cbo:  `bsWhateverYOuCalledIt.Filer = ""`

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! The setup you put me on is just a wow.. Yeah it was bssample:) And that is perfect! Thanks a million :)

Comment: `The setup you put me on` you only have it halfway implemented.  You ought not have to rebuild it after an Add and the DT and/or BS could drive the entire application.

Comment: True that, but from what i am on with it.. Its pretty amazing. Once i finish the program and have extra time i will edit it to try work fully with it. Reason why i am using the way i am now is simply due to the fact its the only way i do now how to do if that makes sense? :L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on previous questions, I know you have a `DataTable` somewhere and a `BindingSource`.  If the intention is for the user to be able to view just the "SalesCustomer" types, use a filter:

```
bsCust.Filter = "SalesCustomer = True"
```

In other cases when the filter target is text:

```
Dim FishFilter = ""
If cboFishFilter.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
    FishFilter = String.Format("Fish = '{0}'", cboFishFilter.Text)
    ' e.g.: "Fish = 'Perch'"
End If

' or via a BindingSource:
bsHdr.Filter = FishFilter
' can also use DataView.RowFilter:
dvHdr.RowFilter = FishFilter
```

How you apply it depends on which objects you are employing.  This allows/assumes that the first item in the list is "(None)" or somesuch so that there is a way to remove any filters.  In that case, `FishFilter` remains an empty string and clears the filter.

I like to put this on an "Apply" button so that a user can open the list and look at it without accidentally applying a filter.

Comment: Thanks again Plutonix!